# Select object and move the view simultaneously

Tags: select, navigation

is there a way to select something (in edit/object, I'm interested to see if this is possible in either mode) from an area of my workspace and then zoom in/out and pan to a different area (off screen at the time of the selection) and place my selection there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> for *Numbers* panel, click the *View* tab, enable *Camera to View*:

[image]

Press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> and adjust your view, or if you already have the correct view, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to set camera to this view.

Now select the object, then the camera (so the camera is active). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then <kbd>O</kbd> to parent the object to the camera.

Now by moving the view you also move the object:

[image]

Comment: Remember you can have more than one camera, if you don't want to mess with the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though that's not what I want to do... It's a very simple feature in other programs (just holding MMB after making a selection and then you're able to move around in the workspace) but, from the sound of it, there's no way to do that in Blender.

Comment: @Kyriakh can you describe how it differs from what you want to do? I didn't show panning (shift + MMB) on the screenshot, but you could pan as well: https://i.imgur.com/gfSRbZO.gif

Comment: Let's say I have a cube in one area of my workspace and a sphere in another. I zoom in real close to the sphere (so that the cube isn't in the view) and now I want to move the sphere near the cube so I select the sphere. Can I move around in the workspace (pan/zoom) while holding the sphere until I find the cube and place the sphere there? I'm oversimplifying as to be clear about what I want to do.

Comment: @Kyriakh what do you mean by *"holding"* the sphere? In the GIFs above I'm holding the Susanne - perhaps you don't want it to scale together with viewport, only to move together with viewport?

Comment: I mean grab the object and move it around (with G). But then the object can only be moved to another place in the workspace that's on screen at the time that you press G. If I want to go beyond that I have to place the object somewhere, move the view (with Shift+MMB) or zoom out (with scroll) and then grab it again with G. Both of these things (Shift+MMB and scroll) don't work when G is "active". The first one is changing the axis that you're moving and the second one doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Kyriakh I see. I think that would require creating a new *"Move"* operator that allows for that by replacing the MMB functionality. Or you could use my solution (I could make it simpler with less steps) so that instead of 1. Press G, 2. move object around, 3. When you also want to move the view, drag MMB, 4. release MMB and again move only your oblect, 5. Click to place the object --> you would do: 1. Ctrl+Shift+Numpad0 as in my answer, then select the object and press G, 2. No change, 3. Click, then drag MMB, 4. release MMB, press G, 5. no change

Comment: I tried the second one but it doesn't work. However, I like the one about creating a new "move" operator (I assume you mean shortcut), so I'll try that one. Thank you very much for all this help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Select the object, go to the desired place, use right click to set the 3D cursor then press Shift S "Selection to cursor".

Comment: So, there's no way to "hold" something and move around at the same time?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Ok thank you very much anyway! I'm used to being able to select something and move the view at the same time (with another program I'm using) so it's been bugging me a lot. It's good to at least know that that's not possible in Blender.